# How to make one object fully cover another and how to get rid of fuzzy edges/corners in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

[image]

Here is the thing: **folder2.svg** is created by me, and **folder1.svg** - by someone else. As you can see on the screenshot the first icon looks crisp and nice, and my icon has fuzzy edges and coners, the background object isn't fully covered, although the objects in my **folder2.svg** file have the same size:

[image]

Can someone, please, help me solve this problem? How do I make such fancy icons as **folder1.svg**?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you post a link to both files please? The sizes you've shown are not the same for each icon. If this is a typo and they're the same size I suspect you just need to remove the stroke from the objects in your version. Hth

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

1. Round the width and height of the object.
2. Enable 1px grid and align object to it.
3. Check X,Y,Width,Height

**Example**

- *Good* x=242px y=54px width=48px height=47px
- *Bad* x=242.002px y=54.4px width=48.5px height=47.999px

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Please explain better what you mean. What are the meanings of x, y, width and height (which unit?).  Why the rounding, what is the advantage? And at last can you show what to do with some scrennshot(s)?

Comment: Look at update. In the picture above the maximum zoom to display the 1pixels  grid.

Comment: For a potential way to automate rounding off the coordinates, see [this SVG optimizer](https://github.com/petercollingridge/SVG-Optimiser)