# Inkscape: how to export image for Android with high quality resolution

Tags: inkscape, file-format, android

I am using Inkscape and want to export an image for an Android resolution with high quality. How can I convert?

When I convert the medium size of icons from Inkscape's 48*48 size that image becomes blurred.

Comment: It seems like your question is missing some details and samples of your original artwork vs what you say looks blurry, and also what exactly you do to export these images. Is it possible for you to add these details?

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82219/how-to-create-proper-vector-images-that-can-be-used-as-an-android-vector-drawabl) and [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70479/inkscape-export-xml-for-android-drawable-resource-directory). If you search for "VectorDrawable", you'll find a lot of similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your SVG icon to a VectorDrawable which is the native vector format of Android. That way you will always have crisp edges on high resolution screens.

There are [online tools](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) which allows you to do the conversion automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55423) question. Usually make the maximum size of the icons, and only then reduce it when exporting, you can use dpi option. Make sure that the icon gets into the pixel grid.

But the best result is draw the each size manually.

Comment: Do you think the kinked question is a duplikate? Or should that be better a comment?

Comment: I think the people who will look for a solution to this problem will find it here. And if you look at the topic given me and for the current, the search queries are different, this will ensure greater coverage of an audience that is looking for an answer to this problem.
And I think, instead of flushing the topic, it is necessary to ask the author of the details and try to help.