# Inkscape: export xml for Android drawable resource directory

Tags: inkscape, svg, export, xml

I am a Newbie in Inkscape. I tried to find a solution on the internet but I didn't find anything about exporting XML for Android drawable resource directory.

I would like to be sure if this program is really unable to convert or export SVG to that XML format. If so, can I export selected icons in this specific XML format?

Comment: I used inkscape to export an `svg` to `plain svg`. It did some changes and made it compatible with vector assert studio without altering visuals of the icon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The XML used for an Android [VectorDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) resource is specific to Android and therefor not something you will easily be able to export from any general image editing software.

You have a number of options.

- Android has [**Vector Asset Studio**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html), with which you can import an SVG file to and export the XML resource you need.
- [**SVG to VectorDrawable Converter**](https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter) is a command line tool that requires Inkscape to run.
- [**Android SVG to VectorDrawable**](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) is an online drag & drop converter.

You should keep in mind that VectorDrawable doesn't support all SVG features. Notably patterns, masks, gradients, images. You are basically limited to basic paths.

Answer (score 0):

Save your file in Inkscape as xfg and open it at any text editor.
You can directly imported from Android Studio

Answer (score -1):

You can use Inkscape to create a SVG file and use a convertor to retrieve a vector XML code for Android with :

- [SVG to Vector Drawable Converter](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/)
- [Android SVG to VectorDrawable](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)

[SVG to Vector Drawable Converter](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) from *a-student* works better than [Android SVG to VectorDrawable](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) from inloop for few SVG files (ignore non visible layer for example).
But both are very good!