# How to create proper Vector Images that can be used as an Android Vector-Drawable?

Tags: vector, inkscape, icon, svg, android

I'm quite new to creating vector images. I started to learn how the create them because I need some custom icons for an Android app I'm currently working on. And here starts the problem. I'm creating the icons using Inkscape and when I try to convert them into a VectorDrawable using Android Studio, it returns an error about not supporting certain things:

```
ERROR@ line 22 <defs> is not supported
WARNING@ line 139 We don't scale the stroke width!
WARNING@ line 144 We don't scale the stroke width!
WARNING@ line 150 We don't scale the stroke width!
WARNING@ line 156 We don't scale the stroke width!
WARNING@ line 162 We don't scale the stroke width!
WARNING@ line 168 We don't scale the stroke width!
WARNING@ line 174 We don't scale the stroke width!
```

I firts tried to somehow convert the path to an object within Inkscape, but this didn't worked. Then I looked for some solutions on the web and found the following website: http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/
There I could convert the icon but now I can only use it android 7.0 and higher because I used the attribute 'fill-rule:evenodd'.

Now here's my question: How to make sure I only use the proper attributes when creating an icon and how can I make my icon work on android?

If you want to follow my attempt at fixing the problem, here you can download my SVG file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/213285061/Foren/Biologie_Icon.svg

Thank you for every advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inkscape: export xml for Android drawable resource directory](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70479/inkscape-export-xml-for-android-drawable-resource-directory)

Comment: @Scribblemacher my problem is not converting an svg to a vector drawable, but rather my usage of "svg attributes" that are not supported by android. I wanted to know how to avoid using those attributes or how to replace them with supported ones.

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate. VectorDrawable is *not* an SVG. If you have an SVG, then it needs to go through some sort of conversion. It's up to that conversion program to map/transform the SVG into a VectorDrawable XML. It's matter of avoiding what isn't supported by your conversion toolchain, which could dozens upon dozens of things (the SVG standard huge).

Comment: For solving your actual problem them, I'd suggest trying to save as "Plain SVG" in Inkscape, which will remove non-standard content that's usually in the `inkscape:` namespace. It's possible that Android Studio is getting tripped up by namespaced data used by Inkscape in the default save format.

Comment: Thank you @Scribblemacher , this actually solved my problem. I didn't thought it would be that easy. For some reason I'm still getting the same error messages while importing to Android Studio, but it works this time. Thank you so much, I've already been looking for hours to fix this.

Comment: glad it helped. I added an answer and some more details on why this probably happens as an answer.

Comment: Saving as a "Plain SVG" in the Inkscape didn't help me. Instead, everything works if you remove the extra grouping of objects in Edit -> XML editor. I simplify icon structure and leave only the root group, then Android Studio correctly create Vector Drawables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

Save as a "Plain SVG" in Inkscape.

Note: As of Inkscape 0.91, if you save as "Plain SVG" and then just do a normal "Save", it will save again as an Inkscape SVG. So you'll need to do save and explicitly select plain SVG each time.

Related question about SVG-to-VectorDrawable conversion: [Inkscape export XML for Android drawable resource directory](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70479/inkscape-export-xml-for-android-drawable-resource-directory)

## Explanation

Inkscape's default save format is "Inkscape SVG", which is a normal SVG file that is compliant with the SVG 1.1 standard, along with metadata and additional information used by Inkscape in the `inkscape` namespace.

That's perfectly valid SVG, and most render programs like browsers have no problem with it. It sounds like your workflow for transforming from SVG to VectorDrawable XML is chocking on that Inkscape-specific code (although `<defs>` is valid vanilla SVG).

Saving as "Plain SVG" removes all that extra data and any features that aren't in the SVG standard. This will result in better compatibility with other programs (like yours), but you may loose some information, depending on the drawing.

### Features to avoid

By far the most common non-standard SVG feature people use is a text flow. These are created by dragging to create a text box (instead of just clicking). Wrapping text is not support in SVG—many programs will just ignore the text.

In the **Text** menu, there's an option in Inkscape for converting a text flow to a normal SVG text object.

In most cases, the offending element can just be converted to a path.

### Tweaking output

In addition to using "Plain SVG", there are a few other features for tweaking the SVG tree in Inkscape's output.

- On the **File** menu, click **Document Cleanup**. This gets rid of un-used defs and other metadata.
- On the **Edit** menu, click **Preferences**. In the **Input/Output** section there's a few options to change the XML

Comment: I ended up converting a text to a path using **Path**, **Object to Path**. Worked like a charm. I'm using Inkscape 0.92 and Android Studio 3.1.3.

Comment: Another feature to avoid: The caps on the ends of lines (eg **arrow heads**), stored in `<marker>` nodes.